# Sub or Function is not executed while the application is hidden

Tags: vb.net

I have a VB.NET application which is hidden on startup using a NotifyIcon.

There's a timer that is executed every 10 seconds... In the timer:

If a file exists nothing will be done. But if it does not exists, I will execute:

```
MySubOrFunction()
```

MySubOrFunction() code is not executed if the application is hidden ... and as I told you above "my application is hidden on startup"

I tried "Public Sub" , "Private Sub" , the same for "Function" too ... also I tried "Shared Function" but it cannot work because some of my codes require access to another code which is not inside the function/sub.

I tried to keep the form opened and everything goes fine , but I want it to be hidden :(

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks! :-)

---

**EDIT: Example is here (sorry for missing it):**

On the Form_Load event:

```
Timer2.Enabled = True
Timer2.Start()
```

Timer2 is executed every 5 seconds and here is Timer2_Tick

```
Timer1.Enabled = True
Timer1.Start()
```

Here is Timer1_Tick

```
MySubOrFunction("start")
```

Here is MySubOrFunction

```
Private Sub MySubOrFunction(ByVal status As String)
    If status = "start" Then
        ' My Code Here
        Return
    End If

    If status = "stop" Then
        Return ' stop the function
    End If
End Sub
```

And here is how I hide my application:

```
Private Sub Form1_Resize(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Resize
        If Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized Then
            NotifyIcon1.Visible = True
            NotifyIcon1.Icon = SystemIcons.Application
            NotifyIcon1.BalloonTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Info
            NotifyIcon1.BalloonTipTitle = "AppName"
            NotifyIcon1.BalloonTipText = "AppDesc"
            NotifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(50000)
            'Me.Hide()
            ShowInTaskbar = False
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub NotifyIcon1_MouseDoubleClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles NotifyIcon1.MouseDoubleClick
        Me.Visible = True
        'Me.Show()
        ShowInTaskbar = True
        Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
        NotifyIcon1.Visible = False
    End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub SetVisibleCore(ByVal value As Boolean)
        If Not Me.IsHandleCreated Then
            Me.CreateHandle()
            value = False
        End If
        MyBase.SetVisibleCore(value)
    End Sub
```

This work fine when the application is not hidden ... and those were just examples and not the full code!

Comment: The function does not run when the application is hidden ONLY , However when the application is not hidden it works good.
So the timer does not have any problem.

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]. How can we offer advice without seeing the code?

Comment: in which form event there is the timer?

Comment: @NikolaosPolygenis The timer is not in any event , it is in its own event (Timer_Tick)

Comment: @Enigmativity I try my best to not paste any code of my project... I will post an example of the same code now...

Comment: try to start the timer on form load: timer.start(). and then hide the form. I have created a similar application and it works...

Comment: @NikolaosPolygenis The timer starts by another time... The another timer is started on the startup . xD

Comment: @MatrixCow08 - Why did you try to **not** post your code?

Comment: @Enigmativity has right, please post your code...

Comment: Done guys! I posted the examples above.

Comment: How do you *hide* your application?

Comment: @MatSnow Sorry I forgot that too! I added it.

Comment: @MatrixCow08 - Could you now please create a new project, pop in the code that you've now posted in your question, and see if the problem still exists? If it does, then let us know. If not, then the code you've posted isn't enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I was using to hide the form was the problem !

I removed the NotifyIcon and removed the following:

```
Private Sub Form1_Resize(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Resize
        If Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized Then
            NotifyIcon1.Visible = True
            NotifyIcon1.Icon = SystemIcons.Application
            NotifyIcon1.BalloonTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Info
            NotifyIcon1.BalloonTipTitle = "AppName"
            NotifyIcon1.BalloonTipText = "AppDesc"
            NotifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(50000)
            'Me.Hide()
            ShowInTaskbar = False
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub NotifyIcon1_MouseDoubleClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles NotifyIcon1.MouseDoubleClick
        Me.Visible = True
        'Me.Show()
        ShowInTaskbar = True
        Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
        NotifyIcon1.Visible = False
    End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub SetVisibleCore(ByVal value As Boolean)
        If Not Me.IsHandleCreated Then
            Me.CreateHandle()
            value = False
        End If
        MyBase.SetVisibleCore(value)
    End Sub
```

***And here is the new way to hide the application on startup***:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ' hide application on startup
    Me.Opacity = 0.0
    Me.ShowInTaskbar = False
    ' ---------------------
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Shown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Shown

        Me.Visible = False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `Form_Load()` isn't executed because of the way you're hiding the Form in `SetVisibleCore`.

Enable the Timer in `Form_HandleCreated()` and it should work.